# PowerEdge T410 with GeForce GTX 970 - Independent power source needed?

Tags: hardware, dell-poweredge, electrical-power, power-supply-unit, graphics-processing-unit

I am attempting to install a [GeForce GTX 970](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814487076) graphics card in our [Dell PowerEdge T410](http://www.dell.com/downloads/emea/products/pedge/en/pedge_T410_Technical_Guidebook_rev1.pdf) server for the purpose of rendering 3D graphics.
After inserting the graphics card into the PCI-E slot it became apparent that this server does not have the cables necessary to power the card.

What would I need to power the card? Would this [SATA Power to 6-pin](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812400106&cm_re=6_pin_pci_express_power_cable-_-12-400-106-_-Product) connector do it? [image: SATA to 6 pin]

If so, then I would need two of those (4 SATA power connectors). I only have two free connectors (the rest are connected to hard drives). Can I use a couple [SATA Power Splitters](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812200468&cm_re=SATA_Power_splitter-_-12-200-468-_-Product) to create the necessary inputs? 
[image: SATA Power Splitter]

If not, is there some sort of independent power unit that we can buy to power the card? Perhaps one of the redundant modular PSUs can be replaced with a PSU that provides the necessary power connections?

[image: Dell PowerEdge T410 with GTX 970]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up trying my first (and cheapest) idea for powering the card. To my surprise it worked without a hitch! To summarize, I successfully powered the **EVGA GeForce GTX 970** using:

```
                 (INPUT)
         PSU
          |
          V 
       2x SATA Power Cable
          |      
          V
       Splitter  (1x SATA => 2x SATA)
          |
          V
       4x SATA Power Cable
          |
          V
       SATA to 6-pin converter (2x SATA => 1x 6-pin)
          |
          V
       2x 6-pin
          |
          V
       GeForce GTX 970
                    (OUTPUT)
```

Comment: You could get away without the splitter if you only plug-in one of the sata to 6pin each. Not using 4 sata outputs is a bit risky in both scenarios,